# Updating Horizontal Scrollview OnGUI

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The thing that I want to do is that when I click the onGUI Button, Scroll view viewRect y axis increase at the same time. It means,I want to update the horizontal scroll view. However, my code is not working. How can I handle this?

```cs
   private void OnGUI()
    {
        int subPartsSpacing = 0;
        float spacing = 30;
        float x = 7 + spacing;
        float y = 68;
        float scrollview_y = 236;

        HumanBodyPart mainBodyPart = bodyVisualizer.BodyData.Body.SubParts[0];
        List<HumanBodyPart> nextPartsToRender = new List<HumanBodyPart>(new HumanBodyPart[] { mainBodyPart });        
        while (nextPartsToRender.Count > 0)
        {

            HumanBodyPart currentPart = nextPartsToRender[0];
            nextPartsToRender.RemoveAt(0);

            scrollPosition = GUI.BeginScrollView(new Rect(7, 68, 236, 426), scrollPosition, new Rect(7, 68, 500, scrollview_y));
            GUI.Label(new Rect(currentPart.DrawDepth * spacing + x + subPartsSpacing, y, 200, 20), currentPart.EnglishTitle);

            if (currentPart.SubParts.Count != 0)
            {
                if (GUI.Button(new Rect(x - spacing + currentPart.DrawDepth * spacing + subPartsSpacing, y, 20, 20), "+"))
                {
                    if (!currentPart.IsExpanded)
                    {
                        currentPart.IsExpanded = true;
                        subPartsSpacing += 20;
                    }
                    else
                        currentPart.IsExpanded = false;
                }
                if (currentPart.IsExpanded)
                {
                    //The wrong part I guess...
                    scrollview_y += 20 * currentPart.SubParts.Count;
                    //
                    nextPartsToRender.InsertRange(0, currentPart.SubParts);
                }
            }
            y += spacing;
        }
        // End the scroll view that we began above.
        GUI.EndScrollView();
    }
```

GUI Error: You are pushing more GUIClips than you are popping. Make sure they are balanced)

Comment: GUI has long been depreciated (outside the editor), why don't you want to use UGUI scrollview?

Answer (score 0):

Shrinked to the esential you are doing

```
while (/*...*/)
{
    // ...
    scrollPosition = GUI.BeginScrollView(/*...*/);
    // ...
}
GUI.EndScrollView();
```

so you get possibly multiple calls of `BeginScrollView` but only one call of `EndScrollView` after the loop.

So rather either move it into the `while` loop so it gets called for every `BeginScrollView` call

```
while (/*...*/)
{
    // ...
    scrollPosition = GUI.BeginScrollView(/*...*/);
    // ...
    GUI.EndScrollView();
}
```

or move both outside depending on your needs ofcourse

```
scrollPosition = GUI.BeginScrollView(/*...*/);
while (/*...*/)
{
    // ...
}
GUI.EndScrollView();
```